# ListView and pointer events - any way to handle this?

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, windows-10

This is quite old and I believe common case - I have a *ListView* and I want to let it handle vertical scroll, but horizontal movement of pointer I would like to handle myself.

There is a [good blog post from Rob Caplan](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsdevsol/2013/02/15/where-did-all-my-gestures-go/), but it's already three years old and I don't know if there had anything changed in W10. In the post, at the end, Rob suggests to avoid scrolling the *ListView* manually from own event. Is there any better, easier way to handle this?

Sample code can look like this:

```xml
<Grid x:Name="mainGrid" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ListView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Transparent" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <x:String>First Item</x:String>
        <x:String>Second Item</x:String>
        <x:String>Third Item</x:String>
        <x:String>Fourth Item</x:String>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

code behind:

```cs
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    mainGrid.PointerMoved += (sender ,e) => Debug.WriteLine("Pointer moved"); 
    mainGrid.AddHandler(PointerPressedEvent, new PointerEventHandler((sender, e) => Debug.WriteLine("Pointer pressed")), true);
    mainGrid.AddHandler(PointerReleasedEvent, new PointerEventHandler((sender, e) => Debug.WriteLine("Pointer released")), true);
}
```

The main problem is that when *ListView's* scrollviewer get pointer event it 'swallows' it. As you can see above we are able to subscribe to pressed/released events so that they gets called anyway, but it's not possible for pointermoved event. Theoretically there should be a way to achieve this, hence for example *ListView* inside *Pivot* works just fine - vertical scroll is performed by *ListView* and horizontal by *Pivot*. How this can be done? Any ideas?

Comment: Had somewhat similar problem in past http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34083064/scrollviewer-absorbing-multiple-pointerreleased-events. Didn't find any workaround.

Comment: @M.Hassan This seems to be connected with all controls that have scrollviewer or other control taking care of pointer events. As it's a routed event it is not passed further after it's handled. Therefore I wonder how the pivot is working with listview inside.

Comment: How the pivot is working with listview inside. I've worked on a similar case once before: [Disable pivot swipe during scrolling on UWP app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35207827/disable-pivot-swipe-during-scrolling-on-uwp-app/35216140#35216140). I just tried the solution there, seems the scenario here is different.

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT Thanks for the comment. Seems like the answer you have posted follows the mentioned Rob Caplan's blog post - disable scrollviewer and take care of events. I would like to avoid that. But the other answer brings some light - seems like pivot is taking advantage of horizontal chaining. I will give it a try and see if I can use that somehow.

Comment: Have you worked this out? By now I still can't find a good practices, if you have any solution, please let me know.

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT No news here. Seems like nothing has changed in this manner for few years. ScrollVeiwer works at very low level and thus it has nice performance, the drawback is that it handles pointer events. In this case the only way will be to disable/enable it. But this also has drawbacks - handling scrollviewer yourself you will lose performance, smooth scrolling. Theoretically you can imitate smoothness, but you will probably lose virtualization. I will have to find a workaround for my problem. Nevertheless, thanks to your comment now I know how pivot is constructed.