# Swipe on grid is ignored on mobile

Tags: c#, uwp, swipe, gesture, windows-10-mobile

I am populating a ListView programmatically when the user selects an entry from a ComboBox.

I'd like to improve the app usability by allowing the user to swipe left/right as an alternative way to change the content.

More exactly when the user performs a flick or short swipe, the listview gets populated with a different set of items. I don't need any visual cue that a manipulation has started (i.e. Like Edge does when using gestures to navigate back and forth)

Below is the simplified XAML structure.

```
<Grid 
  x:Name="MainGrid" 
  ManipulationMode="TranslateX,  TranslateInertia" 
  Loaded="MainGrid_Loaded"> 

  <ComboBox x:Name="CBMonthPicker" />

  <ListView 
      x:Name="LV" 
      ItemsSource="{Binding CalItems, ElementName=page}"                 
      DataContext="MainPage"                  
      IsItemClickEnabled="True"
      ItemClick="OnItemClick"
      ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MyDataTemplateSelector}">          
  </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Here is the code I am using to detect swipe, which works on Desktop (if I simulate a swipe with the mouse), but does not work on mobile (Grid_ManipulationDelta is not triggered on Mobile):

```
    private void MainGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainGrid.ManipulationDelta += Grid_ManipulationDelta;
    }

    private void Grid_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var swiped = e.Cumulative.Translation.X;
        var swipeTriggerThreshhold = 300;
        //if the gesture was not above a set threshold we ignore it
        if (!e.IsInertial || swiped * swiped < swipeTriggerThreshhold * swipeTriggerThreshhold )
            return;            
        //If we got so far, we registered a swipe
        e.Complete(); //end manipulation so we only handle it once  
        if (swiped < 0)  { //we swiped left
            changeDisplayedMonth(-1);
        }
        else{  //we swiped right
            changeDisplayedMonth(1);
        }           
     }
```

My guess is that ListView or ListViewItem(s) are somehow hiding the manipulation from the Grid.

I have tried using the ListView and ListViewItem to handle the manipulation, but ManipulationDelta is never triggered  for any of them, even if I set ManipulationMode to TranslateX, TranslateInertia.

There are plenty of questions on SO regarding swipe for ListViewItem (like featured in Outlook). This question is not related to that.

Because the content is loaded dynamically based on user input, I'd rather not use Pivot. Even if I could, it would mean significant changes to my interface, which again I'd rather not do.

Comment: Just to understand your UI: You have a ListView overlaying the ComboBox and the user can interact with both? Or are they below each other?

Comment: The combobox and the listview share the same grid (MainGrid in my XAML sample), but are placed on separate rows. They don't overlap. Worth noting that swipe works on mobile if I swipe on the combobox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of fiddling around with Pivot which yielded completely unsatisfactory results, I have discovered FlipView which could be used with a bit of hacking to accomplish exactly what I wanted.

The trick is to add two dummy FlipViewItems, one before the one containing our ListView, and one after it. The next step is to capture the SelectionChanged event of the FlipView and if the FlipViewItem before our content has been selected, trigger an action as you would for a back swipe, the same for the FlipViewItem after our content.
The last step is to force selection back to our content ListViewItem.

A small annoyance with FlipView hacked in this manner is that, when forcing selection back to our middle FlipViewItem (the one hosting our content), the animation is opposite to the one expected by the end user. This is easily fixed by setting the property UseTouchAnimationsForAllNavigation="False" on the FlipView.

Bonus: To show that something is actually happening while repopulating the ListView, I have added a progress ring. For this to work, it is important that the FlipView and FlipViewItems and the ListView have their Background Property set to Transparent. And the ListViewItems have a specified background to cover it. This is a totally inelegant solution for implementing a ProgressRing, however it works and it was fast to come up with :).

So this is how the updated XAML code looks like:

```
<Grid x:Name="MainGrid" > 
  <ComboBox x:Name="CBMonthPicker" Grid.Row="0"/>

  <ProgressRing  Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsActive="True"  />

  <FlipView  x:Name="MainView"  Grid.Row="1"  
               Loaded="MainView_Loaded"
               UseTouchAnimationsForAllNavigation="False" 
               Background="Transparent">

      <FlipViewItem Background="Transparent">               
      </FlipViewItem>

      <FlipViewItem Background="Transparent">
         <ListView  x:Name="LV" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding CalItems, ElementName=page}" DataContext="MainPage"                  
            IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="OnItemClick"
            ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MyDataTemplateSelector}">          
         </ListView>
      </FlipViewItem>

      <FlipViewItem Background="Transparent">               
      </FlipViewItem>

</Grid>
```

And this is how the code behind looks like:

```
    private void MainView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainView.SelectedIndex = 1;
        MainView.SelectionChanged += MainView_SelectionChanged;
    }

    private void MainView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MainView.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            //perform the action for Back Swipe Gesture
            changeDisplayedMonth(-1);

            //force selection back to our content FlipViewItem
            MainView.SelectedIndex = 1;               
        }
        if (MainView.SelectedIndex == 2)
        {
            //perform the action for Forward Swipe Gesture 
            changeDisplayedMonth(1);

            //force selection back to our content FlipViewItem               
            MainView.SelectedIndex = 1;                
        }            
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your guess is right - *ListView* has a *ScrollViewer* which is working on a very low level, which improves the performance, however its taking care of manipulations first and thus it 'swallows' them. It seems that some time ago seems I've asked [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36737422/2681948).

There is a way to manually handle this case - [Rob Caplan's blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsdevsol/2013/02/15/where-did-all-my-gestures-go/) describes it a little, it's quite old, but should bring you some light. You may also take a look [at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23672239/2681948), where it's described for *Windows-Runtime*, which should also work similar on *UWP*.

Note also that it may be easier to do what you want - if you put your *ListView* in *Pivot* or something with horizontal *ScrollViewer*, you may change the property [IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ScrollViewer#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_ScrollViewer_IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled) of *ListView's* *ScrollViewer* to true, which will pass horizontal scroll to a parent. Here is a sample XAML code:

```xml
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <ListView Width="200" Height="100" ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled="True">
                <x:String>First Item</x:String>
                <x:String>Item</x:String>
                <x:String>Item</x:String>
                <x:String>Item</x:String>
                <x:String>Last Item</x:String>
            </ListView>
            <Rectangle Width="200" Height="100" Fill="Red"/>
            <Rectangle Width="200" Height="100" Fill="Green"/>
            <Rectangle Width="200" Height="100" Fill="Blue"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Comment: If I understand correctly your approach is to implement vertical scrolling manually for listview while also capturing and handling swipe gestures. What I also read from your answer to the other question is that scroll smoothness is lost during this operation. I'd rather not got that route if this is the case. Also your other suggestion of wrapping the listview with horizontal scrolling containers did not work. Not only is the ManipulationDelta event never triggered (on any of the containers and the listview itself), but layout is seriously broken when doing so.

Comment: @brett I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve at the end. If you are chaining scrolls like in the xaml sample, then you don't need ManiplationDelta, have you tried just this code on fresh app? Additionally if you need some more logic on scrolling you may always subscribe to horizontal scrollviewer's events.

Comment: I have updated the question to clarify my desired outcome. I have no horizontal scroll anywhere in my app. Only vertical.