# UWP PivotItem ListView TabChange issue

Tags: .net, win-universal-app, windows-10, windows-10-universal

I am encountering strange problem. I have `Pivot` in my Xaml like this:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="NavButtonPressedBackgroundBrush" Color="White" Opacity="0.3" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="NavButtonCheckedBackgroundBrush" Color="White" Opacity="0.2" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="NavButtonHoverBackgroundBrush" Color="White" Opacity="0.1" />

        <Style x:Key="NavRadioButtonStyle" TargetType="RadioButton">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
                        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGrid">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource NavButtonHoverBackgroundBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGrid">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource NavButtonPressedBackgroundBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled" />
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGrid">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource NavButtonCheckedBackgroundBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Focused"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Grid Name="BackgroundGrid" Background="Transparent" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="48"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock FontSize="34" Height="38" Text="{TemplateBinding Tag}" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Margin="5,8,5,5" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Page.Resources>


<SplitView  x:Name="MySplitView" DisplayMode="CompactOverlay" IsPaneOpen="False" 
            CompactPaneLength="48" OpenPaneLength="240" PaneBackground="DarkGray">
    <SplitView.Pane>
        <StackPanel x:Name="SplitViewPanel">

            <RadioButton x:Name="HamburgerRadioButton" Click="HamburgerRadioButton_Click" Style="{StaticResource NavRadioButtonStyle}"
                         Background="Gray" GroupName="Hamburger" Tag="" />

            <RadioButton x:Name="HomeRadioButton" Click="HomeRadioButton_Click" Style="{StaticResource NavRadioButtonStyle}"
                         Background="Gray" Content="Home" GroupName="Navigation" Tag=""/>

            <RadioButton x:Name="SettingRadioButton" Click="SettingRadioButton_Click" Style="{StaticResource NavRadioButtonStyle}"
                         Background="Gray" Content="Settings" GroupName="Navigation" Tag=""/>

        </StackPanel>
    </SplitView.Pane>
    <SplitView.Content>
        <SplitView Background="Azure" IsPaneOpen="True" OpenPaneLength="400" DisplayMode="Inline">
            <!--To Show Listing-->
            <SplitView.Pane>
                <Frame Name="FrameListing">
                    <RelativePanel>
                        <!--List Pane Header-->

                            <TextBlock Text="MY RISKS" Name="ListHeaderPanelTitle" RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True" Padding="10"/>
                            <Button Name="ListHeaderAdd" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="" 
                                    RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True" Background="Transparent" Padding="10"/>
                            <Button Name="ListHeaderFilter" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="" 
                                    RelativePanel.LeftOf="ListHeaderAdd" Background="Transparent" Padding="10"/>

                        <!--Tabs Layout-->
                        <Pivot x:Name="rootPivot" RelativePanel.Below="ListHeaderPanelTitle">
                            <PivotItem Header="Assigned">
                                <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Risks}"  IsItemClickEnabled="True" 
                                           ItemClick="ListView_ItemClick" x:Name="AssignedRisksList">
                                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Risk">
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                            <TextBlock FontSize="10" Text="{x:Bind Status}"/>
                                            <TextBlock FontSize="16" Text="{x:Bind Description}"/>
                                            <TextBlock FontSize="14" Text="{x:Bind AssignedTo}"/>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                </ListView>
                                <!--<TextBlock Text="Assigned Listing will go here."/>-->
                            </PivotItem>
                            <PivotItem Header="Logged">
                                <TextBlock Text="Logged Listing will go here."/>
                            </PivotItem>
                            <PivotItem Header="All" >
                                <TextBlock Text="All Listing will go here."/>
                            </PivotItem>
                        </Pivot>

                    </RelativePanel>
                </Frame>
            </SplitView.Pane>
            <!--To SHow Detail-->
            <SplitView.Content>
                <Frame Name="FrameRiskDetail">

                </Frame>
            </SplitView.Content>
        </SplitView>
    </SplitView.Content>
</SplitView>
```

The problem is that when I run the application, it shows me **Assigned** pivot item or tab as selected and shows list(`ListView`). However as soon as I try to change tab/PivotItem, nothing happens. Tabs do not change. And when I click again on **Assigned** tab, list disappears.

Now when I set `SelectedIndex="1"` and run app, it shows **Logged** tab as selected and every other tab works fine and shows no improper behavior even list doesn't disappear on **Assigned** tab.

```
<Pivot x:Name="rootPivot" RelativePanel.Below="ListHeaderPanelTitle" SelectedIndex="1">
```

I want to show **Assigned** tab as default selected tab. Even setting `SelectedIndex="0"` doesn't solve the problem.

What I am doing wrong?

**NOTE:** If more information is required, I will share it.

Thanks

Comment: I checked portion of the code provided by you, looks like working as per your expectation. May be your pivot is spanning over entire page, so try to swipe from one side to another side. Let me know if issue is still there.

Comment: Swiping is not working at all. See my updated xaml code.

Comment: It is problem of pivot width. Pivot width may be set to infinite (default value), thus the gesture complete event was not capturing properly. If you set the width to some definite available value inside your splitview pane then it will work. To make your code more better and dynamic, make the pivot width relatively/element bind to the width of the splitview open pane. See my solution comment. I have updated the pivot portion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible issue is with the width of the Pivot as I mentioned earlier. Please try to define some width of the pivot. I marked your pivot width as your open split pane. Now it is working fine. Just keep in mind swipe will be captured only on any visual element. Thus if you try to swipe at very below of the screen it will not work. To make it work you have to define a container there again. I used your code and modified in the pivot section. Below is the code portion use it and test.

```
                            <!--Tabs Layout-->
                        <Pivot x:Name="rootPivot" RelativePanel.Below="ListHeaderPanelTitle" Width="400">
                            <PivotItem Header="Assigned">
                                <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Risks}" IsItemClickEnabled="True" 
                                       ItemClick="ListView_ItemClick" x:Name="AssignedRisksList">
                                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Risk">
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                                <TextBlock FontSize="10" Text="{x:Bind Status}"/>
                                                <TextBlock FontSize="16" Text="{x:Bind Description}"/>
                                                <TextBlock FontSize="14" Text="{x:Bind AssignedTo}"/>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                </ListView>
                                <!--<TextBlock Text="Assigned Listing will go here."/>-->
                            </PivotItem>
                            <PivotItem Header="Logged">
                                <TextBlock Text="Logged Listing will go here."/>
                            </PivotItem>
                            <PivotItem Header="All">
                                <TextBlock Text="All Listing will go here."/>
                            </PivotItem>
                        </Pivot>
```

Comment: Yes, It was width issue. I specified `Width="400"` and all worked like charm. Thanks Kiran Paul. Just one more thing. How I can specify Width equals to its parent's container width?